# CMAKE and cross compiling

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I have to change sysroot for my cmake. There is rootfs located on my disk in /u02/rootfs.

I created toolchain_rootfs file and added this config into it:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/u02/rootfs")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
#set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin/c++")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)


###
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/lib")
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/lib")
```

After that I run cmake with option:

```
cmake ../myproject/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/u02/myproject/toolchain_rootfs
```

And got error like this:

```
------------  /u02/rootfs/usr/lib
------------  /u02/rootfs/usr/lib
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /u02/rootfs/usr/bin/gcc
------------  /u02/rootfs/usr/lib
-- Check for working C compiler: /u02/rootfs/usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/u02/rootfs/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /u02/myproject/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_0e039/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_0e039.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_0e039.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory '/u02/myproject_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0e039.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /u02/rootfs/usr/bin/gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_0e039.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /u02/myproject_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  /u02/rootfs/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1:
  error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.10: cannot open shared
  object file: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me please solve this error.  I went through cmake manual, set RPATH, but it doesn't work to me.  What is wrong?

UDP1:

I've tried to use sysroot, without toolchain like:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/u02/rootfs")
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

CMAKE was passed, but MAKE was failed. I got error:

```
/u02/rootfs/usr/bin/ar: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.25-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

rootfs has this library.

How to specify PATH to LIBs in rootfs(sysroot)?

Comment: libisl.so.10 is placed in rootfs.

Comment: Looks like you want to use compiler on the target machine (at `/usr/bin/gcc`) as a *cross-compiler*. This doesn't work: target compiler works only on target machine, it doesn't work on other machine even if you mount target's filesystem. You need actual cross-compiler.

Comment: thank, I did update

Comment: `I've tried to use sysroot, without toolchain like` - **sysroot** can be used **only with toolchain**, see documentation for variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html). Again, your problem is not in using toolchain, your problem is using **improper compiler for cross-compilation**.

Comment: Also, when change toolchain file, do not forget to clear `CMakeCache.txt` file (or clear entire build directory). Your last error seems as a result of cached value (`/u02/rootfs/usr/bin/ar`) from the previous toolchain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   What do you mean with phrase "improper compiler for cross-compilation"? I just want to use compiler from external SDK ( /u02/rootfs/usr/bin/gcc ) with its libs  -  Is there anything against it?

Comment: According to the path (`/usr/bin/gcc` under sysroot), your compiler is only for **target machine**: it works only when executed on that machine. You attemp to use that compiler on host machine. It doesn't work such way. Again, you need **cross-compiler**, and *normal* compilers aren't suited for that role.

Comment: BTW, as you have compiler on your target machine, you may build the project on that machine, **without cross-compilation**. Cross-compilation is used when you cannot compile files on target machine.

Comment: Tsyvarev, thank you